# How do I get a list of running applications by using the command line?

Tags: command-line, gui, window

I want to list only running application like: Firefox, gedit, Nautilus, etc. using the command line.

Note: I don't want to list all running process, only applications which are running (say manually launched GUIs).

Comment: "only list application which is running" what do you mean? all applications (known also as processes) are running. You mean only opened windows, like 'firefox, empathy and thunderbird' or all process that your user started like 'unity, compiz, gnome-terminal, apt-get'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A combination of `wmctrl` and `xprop`  offers many possibilities.

**Example 1:**

```bash
running_gui_apps() {

    # loop through all open windows (ids)
    for win_id in $( wmctrl -l | cut -d' ' -f1 ); do 

        # test if window is a normal window
        if  $( xprop -id $win_id _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE | grep -q _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL ) ; then 

            echo "$( xprop -id $win_id WM_CLASS | cut -d" " -f4- )"", window id: $win_id"

        fi

    done
}
```

The output could look in this case similar like this:

```
"Firefox", window id: 0x032000a9
"Gnome-terminal", window id: 0x03a0000c
"Thunar", window id: 0x03600004
"Geany", window id: 0x03c00003
"Thunar", window id: 0x0360223e
"Mousepad", window id: 0x02c00003
"Mousepad", window id: 0x02c00248
"Xfce4-terminal", window id: 0x03e00004
```

**Example 2:**

```bash
running_gui_apps() {
    applications=()

    # loop through all open windows (ids)
    for win_id in $( wmctrl -l | cut -d' ' -f1 ); do 

        # test if window is a normal window
        if  $( xprop -id $win_id _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE | grep -q _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL ) ; then 

            # filter application name and remove double-quote at beginning and end
            appname=$( xprop -id $win_id WM_CLASS | cut -d" " -f4 )
            appname=${appname#?}
            appname=${appname%?}

            # add to result list
            applications+=( "$appname" ) 

        fi

    done

    # sort result list and remove duplicates  
    readarray -t applications < <(printf '%s\0' "${applications[@]}" | sort -z | xargs -0n1 | uniq)

    printf -- '%s\n' "${applications[@]}" 
}
```

Output example:

```
Firefox
Geany
Gnome-terminal
Mousepad
Thunar
Xfce4-terminal
```

You can add the function to your `~/.bashrc` or run it from an script file.

Comment: Up-voted due two reasons: (1) it actually answered the question; and, (2), most importantly, didn't try to complicate the question with additional information that very clearly weren't in the scope of the question - these kind of information cause more confusion to the users than help them (us) to understand and solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`wmctrl -l` could be a thing you wanted. First install it

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

You can also combine it with System Monitor's list, by default it shows "All my processes" which means all process that belong to you as a user.

To have only names of applications, run:

EDIT:

```
wmctrl -l|awk '{$3=""; $2=""; $1="";  print $0}'
```

Comment: OP wants to get only the application name. Is this possible?

Comment: no, i opened firefox browser. Your command shows `0x03c000b3  0 avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500 How list of running applications by command? - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox` plus some extra lines about Desktop,Hud,etc.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: sorry, I am working on it, I will add asap an edition, thanks for your attention

Comment: @AvinashRaj this is an addition, `wmctrl -l|awk '{out=""; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){out=$out" "$i}; print $out}'`, will add to my answer. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: sorry , won't works for me.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov `wmctrl -l|awk '{out=""; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){out=$out" "$i}; print $out}'` Not working and getting error `awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
 FILENAME="-" FNR=1 NR=1
`

Comment: sorry gentlemen, I don't know how it happened, that is the correct command:`wmctrl -l|awk '{$3=""; $2=""; $1="";  print $0}'` will add at the final answer's edition

Comment: But with this command you only get the title of the open windows and thats often not the name of the application...

Answer (score 2):

### Introduction

The power of `xdotool` and `wmctrl` comes out when you need to perform manipulation on the windows, such as moving or resizing. However, I strongly believe that for the purpose of only *listing* running programs and information about them, `xprop` and `qdbus` are two sufficient tools and installing `xdotool` and `wmctrl` unless the user wants those for additional functionality - is a purposeless task. In this answer I would like to present two scripting solutions with `xprop` and `qdbus`.

Note that I am by no means against `xdotool` or `wmctrl`. I've used them extensively myself , but I find them more powerful when combined with other tools. Here are just a few examples where I've used them :

- [Creating workspace-dependent shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/a/758307/295286)
- [Moving all windows from one workspace to another](https://askubuntu.com/a/758339/295286)

#### Xprop

The script bellow uses only xprop to extract list of the active windows , filter out only true windows ( not dock type suck as Unity Launcher or Unity Panel ) and display their info:

Demo:

```
$ bash xprop_windows.sh                                                        
XID TYPE    TITLE
--------------------------------

56623112| "x-terminal-emulator", "X-terminal-emulator"| "sakura"

81789126| "Navigator", "Firefox"| "Restore Session - Mozilla Firefox"

82002372| "Navigator", "Firefox"| "gui - How do I get a list of running applications by using the command line? - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox"

33554444| "gnome-terminal", "Gnome-terminal"| "\"Terminal\""

33554486| "gnome-terminal", "Gnome-terminal"| "\"Terminal\""
```

Script [source](https://gist.github.com/SergKolo/6557abd5334d7175a5a387e42fddaebd):

```
get_hex_xids()
{
xprop -root -notype _NET_CLIENT_LIST | \
     awk 'BEGIN{printf "ibase=16"}\
     {gsub(/\,/," ");for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) \
     if ($i~/0x/) printf ";%s",substr(toupper($i),3)   }'  
}

convert_hex2dec()
{
  HEXIDS=$(get_hex_xids)
  echo $HEXIDS | bc
}

print_header()
{
  printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "XID" "TYPE" "TITLE"
  printf "%s\n" "--------------------------------"
}

list_info()
{
  convert_hex2dec | while read line;
  do
  TYPE=$( xprop -id $line _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE | awk -F '=' '{print $2}'   )
  if [ $TYPE != "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL"   ]; then
     continue
  fi
  CLASS=$(xprop -id $line WM_CLASS | awk -F '=' '{print $2}' )
  NAME=$( xprop -id $line _NET_WM_NAME | awk -F '=' '{print $2}'   )
  printf "\n%s|%s|%s\n" "$line" "$CLASS" "$NAME"

  done
}
print_header
list_info
```

#### Qdbus

The code bellow performs essentially the same task, however it filters out applications first, then lists its children windows , and finally provides info about them.

Sample run:

```
$ bash ~/bin/qdbus_windows.sh                                                  
Name: Terminal
Active :false
Children:
33554486|false|""Terminal""
33554444|false|""Terminal""
--------------
Name: Firefox Web Browser
Active :false
Children:
82002372|false|"gui - How do I get a list of running applications by using the command line? - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox"
81789126|false|"Restore Session - Mozilla Firefox"
--------------
Name: MY CUSTOM TERMINAL
Active :true
Children:
56623112|true|"sakura"
--------------
```

Code itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_window_paths()
{
  qdbus org.ayatana.bamf  /org/ayatana/bamf/matcher org.ayatana.bamf.matcher.WindowPaths
}

get_running_apps()
{
  qdbus org.ayatana.bamf /org/ayatana/bamf/matcher org.ayatana.bamf.matcher.RunningApplications
}

list_children()
{
 qdbus org.ayatana.bamf "$1"  org.ayatana.bamf.view.Children
}

window_info()
{
for window in "$@" ; do
 XID=${window##*/}
 TYPE=$(qdbus org.ayatana.bamf $window org.ayatana.bamf.window.WindowType)                                         
 NAME="$(qdbus org.ayatana.bamf $window org.ayatana.bamf.view.Name)"
 ACTIVE=$(qdbus org.ayatana.bamf $window org.ayatana.bamf.view.IsActive)
 MONITOR=$(qdbus org.ayatana.bamf $window org.ayatana.bamf.window.Monitor)
# printf "%s|%s|%s|%s\n" $TYPE $MONITOR $ACTIVE "$NAME" 
 printf "%s|%s|\"%s\"\n" $XID $ACTIVE "$NAME" 
done
}

window_paths=( $( get_window_paths | tr '\n' ' ') )
apps_list=( $( get_running_apps | tr '\n' ' ' ) )

for app in ${apps_list[@]} ; do
#echo $app
  printf "Name: "
  qdbus org.ayatana.bamf $app org.ayatana.bamf.view.Name
  printf "Active :"
  qdbus org.ayatana.bamf $app org.ayatana.bamf.view.IsActive
  printf "Children:\n"
#  list_children $app
  windows=( $( list_children $app | tr '\n' ' ' ) )
  window_info "${windows[@]}"
  printf "%s\n"  "--------------"
done
```

A bit simpler command but requires filtering out the output uses Unity's window stack dbus interface. Here is essentially a [function](https://gist.github.com/SergKolo/411d69b3a6ae9b0d2873d166e090b19f) I have in my `.mkshrc`

```
window_stack()
{
  qdbus --literal com.canonical.Unity.WindowStack  
        /com/canonical/Unity/WindowStack  \
        com.canonical.Unity.WindowStack.GetWindowStack | \
  awk -F '{' '{gsub(/\}|\]|,/,"");gsub(/\[/,"\n");print $2}' | \
  awk '!/compiz/&&!/^$/ && $4!="\""$3"\""  { L[n++] = $0 }\
       END { while(n--) print L[n] }'
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ window_stack
Argument: (usbu) 56623112 "x-terminal-emulator" true 0 
Argument: (usbu) 82002372 "firefox" false 0 
Argument: (usbu) 81789126 "firefox" false 0 
Argument: (usbu) 33554486 "gnome-terminal" false 0 
Argument: (usbu) 33554444 "gnome-terminal" false 0
```

Examples of qdbus usage:

- [Finding gnome-terminal's focused window and its pid](https://askubuntu.com/a/754489/295286)